# find and delete NAN values with matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, nan

I'm trying to receive excel files and merge them into one Excel sheet with some rules:

- copy only rows that have dates at the first column (I'm checking that there are 2 slashes in the cell)
- there should be no rows that are the same (I'm checking that there are no same dates in the merged cell array and same strings at the second column)
- if there is 'NaN' value in the second column - then that row should be removed

In order to do the last rule I'm trying to use this two "if" options:

```
if(isempty(raw{row, 2}))
%if (any(isnan(raw{row, 2})))
        A(index,:) = [];
        index = index -1;
        counter = counter+1;
end
```

This checks if the value at the second column is 'nan' and then removes that row and moves the index back

When I use 'isnan' the program doesn't filter the 'nan' values and the counter=0
when I use 'isempty' the program removes the 'nan' values though the counter stays 0... so the row removal happens in some other way I don't understand

This is the full code:

```
MyFolderInfo = dir('C:\B\Export*.xls'); 
mainfilename = 'C:\B\test - Copy - Copy (9).xlsx';

counter=0;

for FileNum = 1:length(MyFolderInfo)
    [~,~,raw] = xlsread(MyFolderInfo(FileNum).name,1); 
    [~,~,mainraw] = xlsread(mainfilename,1); 
    [num_rows, ~] = size(raw);
    index = 0;
    
    for row = 1:num_rows
          if (sum(ismember(raw{row, 1}, '/')) == 2) && (~any(strcmp(mainraw(:, 2),raw{row, 2})))
              index = index +1; 
              A(index,:) = raw(row,:);
              if( isempty(raw{row, 2}) ==1)
              %if (any(isnan(raw{row, 2})))
                  A(index,:) = [];
                  index = index -1;
                  counter = counter+1
              end
              if(sum(ismember(raw{row, 2}, '/')) == 2)
                  A(index,2:end-1) = raw(row,3:end);
              end
          end
    end
    writecell(A,mainfilename,'Sheet',1,'WriteMode','append');
end
```

When I comment out the if block, I get 609 rows in the merged Excel.

When I use if 'isempty' option, I get 540 rows in the merged Excel and counter = 7

When I use if 'isnan' option, I get 577 rows in the merged Excel and counter = 0

Where can it remove those rows if the program doesn't go into that if conditional?

Comment: Where are you checking that counter = 0? Your counter gets re-initialized to 0 for every file, so if you only check at the end of the outer loop and the last file doesn't have any NaNs that would explain it.

Comment: Regarding why isempty works and isnan doesn't, perhaps xslread automatically treats NaN cells as empty? Not sure about this.

Comment: you  i did accidentally re-initialized to 0 for every file
with 'isempty' i get counter = 7  though the matrix with this deleting rows conditional has 69 more rows so it still deletes some rows else where
while with 'isnan' the counter stay at 0 and it deletes 32 rows else where

Comment: Did you check how the "automatically" removed rows were different from the ones cought by the if statement? Maybe those rows are completely empty, or contain some weird character?